# How to install the node in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, django, docker

I want to install the node v18 in on AWS Linux

Prerequisite

- I have Django and frontend React system. So, I want to use node when installing frontend.
- If I use make Dockerfile such as `From node:18`  it works, but I want to use `FROM python:3.9` to django work.
- Is it not a good idea to put Djang and React in the same container?

Now my docker file is like this.

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN pip install pipenv
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend_react
RUN npm install --force
RUN node -v //version 12 is installed
RUN dnf module install nodejs:18/common
RUN node -v
RUN npm run build
```

Howeber there is no `dnf`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What does "Howeber there is no dnf." mean?

Comment: "Is it not a good idea to put Djang and React in the same container?" It's fine. You can put whatever you want in a container.

Comment: If you have separate frontend and backend apps, then it's best to separate their images and containers. It makes scaling backend using Docker Swarm so much easier later on

Comment: Thankyou @D Malan  I understand I can put this in the same container.

Comment: @TrueGopnik Thank you , I understand I can use both way.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use prebuilt Docker Hub images then this is much easier.  I would generally avoid trying to put components with different use cases, build systems, and runtimes into the same image if possible.

In the specific case of a Django application with a React frontend, you might be compiling the frontend to static files that you then serve directly via Django.  In this setup, you don't need Node to *run* the application, just so long as the static files exist then Django can serve them up.  Docker's [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) feature will let you build the front-end using a `node` image, then `COPY` it into your application.  A typical example might look like:

```bash
FROM node:18 AS react
WORKDIR /app
COPY frontend_react/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY fronend_react/ ./
RUN npm build

FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./
COPY --from=react /app/dist/ frontend_react/dist/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

The first half should look like a normal React image build, except that it doesn't have a `CMD`.  The second half should look like a normal Django image build, plus the `COPY --from=react` line to get the built application from the first build stage.  We don't need `node` or `npm` in the final image, only the static files, and so we don't invoke a package manager to try to install them.

Comment: Ah I can use two `FROM` key. I will try this.